# Upload a Image on clientside using jquery

Tags: jquery, file-upload, upload

Can anyone tell how to upload image in HTML on clientside. The image should be displayed on client side in HTML page.

I use the code of the following link:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

But it is not working in IE.

So I try to change my design like using path of the file but as the browser say it as fakepath which doesnt work for me.

So I dont know how to support IE for uploading Images.

Please can any help me,how to use upload images on client using jquery.I dont want any php plugin or code.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

FileReader does not seem to be supported by IE.

More details in SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5570871/html5-filereader-alternative)

I like the library suggested in the same answer [FancyUpload](http://digitarald.de/project/fancyupload/)

Answer (score 0):

My favourite image uploader is

http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/