# input type file is not working in IE 8

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

OK this works fine in chrome, safari and etc.

but it doesn't work in IE8

**input**

```
<input accept="image/png,image/gif,image/jpeg" id="user_profile_photo" name="user_profile[photo]" type="file">
```

**javasciprt**

```
$("#user_profile_photo").change(function(){
  imageIsDelete = false;
    readURL(this);
}); 

function readURL(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function (e) {
      if(imageSizeValidationCheck(input.files[0].size)){
        $('#myprofile_image').attr('src', e.target.result); 
      }
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}
function imageSizeValidationCheck(size){
  if(size/1024>200){
    alert("Please upload image size lower then 200KB");
    $("#user_profile_photo").replaceWith($("#user_profile_photo").clone( true ) );
    return false;
  }else{
    return true;
  }
}
```

I debugged this in IE dev tool, and the problem was

```
input.files
```

it doesn't exist in IE8(but it works in chrome)

is there an another way to check image size in here?

Comment: `FileReader` is not yet supported in IE:

Comment: @SridharR, supported but from 10th+ version, see: http://caniuse.com/filereader

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`FileReader` is a feature of HTML5 File API, which is supported in IE from 10th version:

http://caniuse.com/filereader

Comment: Any alternative solution for this?

Comment: @Canna : have you checked this thread => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5570871/html5-filereader-alternative

Comment: @Canna You can use HTML4 with chunks to immitate fileuploader with the progress bar/multiupload. But for HTML4 you must also use `<iframe>`, because it will send a single POST, which shall block the current thread for window, so you ought to use it in different window (that's why `<iframe>` is needed). BUT!!! It's the solution for old browsers and nowdays it's bad to support such features. Because it's a waste of time, just try to challange your users to use modern browser with full HTML5/CSS3 and other APIs. It will be more useful both for you as for developer and for your users.