# HTML5 FileReader alternatives as of 2015?

Tags: javascript, html, cross-browser, filereader

my question is simple and might be linked to [earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5570871/html5-filereader-alternative) (2012) question about alternatives of FileReader functionality, and I am in a need of an updated information as of current time - year 2015.

The following link specifies the versions of browsers in which FileReader is currently not supported: IE<10, Opera Mini, Firefox <25, Chrome <31 and etc:
http://caniuse.com/#feat=filereader

So, the question is whether or not there is a way to make it work always? If there isn't - what are the alternatives to use for the maximum coverage of browsers and versions? Maybe there is a pure JS version of code that will always work, support multiple files and etc? Or do we still have to use Flash?

EDIT:

Despite the marking as duplicate I don't think that my question is really that way. I still want answers and the person who marked the question as duplicate was not able to provide an up-to-date answer instead of a 3 year old question that I already linked to my question before his marking as duplicate.

Comment: Why would browsers have implemented new alternatives to FileReader after the standard was written?

Comment: It doesn't work in IE8 and IE9?

Comment: They haven't released new versions of IE 8 and IE 9 with new features. They released IE 10 instead.

Comment: So, my question is what can I use instead of FileReader that would work the same way in IE8 and IE9, or if users are using Opera Mini, or have old Firefox, Chrome and etc... there might have been new libraries or scripts that handle that kind of thing. Are you sure my question is duplicate?

Comment: Yes, the question is a duplicate. If there are new answers to it, they belong on the existing question.

Comment: Alright, how do I make that question a new one so that people look at it and update the answers or post new info to it?

Comment: I can't find any mechanisms to attract attention to questions with accepted answers.

Comment: Which is why I created a new one and also linked an old question to it. After 3 years - there's got to be something new available. But, since you made it a duplicate noone will look here =(

Comment: Why should there be something new? A standard was created. New development is focused around the standard. Old browsers aren't adding new features that allow the problem to be solved in different ways.

Comment: Can you name one uniform solution that works in all browsers all versions and allows users to upload multiple files with dropbox zone to which I can drag&drop files from my computer? FileReader is almost there, but not quite covers everything. My question is about alternatives to FileReader, and I think in 3 years since it was last asked there's got to be some new scripts created that are answering that kind of problem. Don't you think so?

Comment: you can use a polyfill: http://afarkas.github.io/webshim/demos/index.html#FileReader

Comment: How are you going to support users who have Javascript disabled?

Comment: It is another can of worms altogether.. but, anyways, this question was marked up as a duplicate. Although I don't agree with that mark - I don't have an authority to change it.