# Input file onChange IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, file-upload

I have the next code that works in chrome and firefox, however IE send 'undefined' message.

```
<input type="file" name="image" onchange="inputFileChange(this);"/>

function inputFileChange(el) {
    console.log($(el).context.files);
}
```

This is the result of console.log in firefox and chrome.

```
FileList
    0: File
        lastModifiedDate: Thu Dec 20 2012 19:01:23 GMT-0600 (Hora estándar central (México))
        name: "izq02_a.jpg"
        size: 69767
        type: "image/jpeg"
```

...and this is the result in IE

```
REGISTER: undefined
```

I need the filesize of the image before upload, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE10 has partial support for the file API, but earlier versions have none.

[Here's an old question on the topic.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055724/flash-alternative-for-filereader-html-5-api)  People have used Flash solutions as a workaround (well and as the only way possible before the File API existed).

You can use [CanIUse](http://caniuse.com) to check on browser support for various things, as well as [HTML5Please](http://html5please.us).

Comment: Seems that I can do it using Scripting.FileSystemObject but it depends of IE security configuration.

Comment: F**k ! great link @Pointy CandIUse is really usefull

Comment: Yes both those sites are nice - the answers can be depressing sometimes though :-)